# Twitter4J get latest tweets

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

How do I get the latest tweets on twitter? I realise `Search` exists but it wont take a blank query. Basically, I just want to get recent tweets from anywhere with any content. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the [streaming API](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#streaming) ? With the `sample` function, you don't have to provide any criteria and will get a samples of all tweets.